# Java custom Annotation aggregate multiple annotations

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, annotations

Im writing a `TestCases` for my `RestControllers`
For each `ControllerTest calss` I use the following annotations

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(value = SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebConfig.class, TestAppConfig.class})
```

So, I decided to define my own annotation witch contain all those annotations like this

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Inherited
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(value = SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {WebConfig.class, TestAppConfig.class})
public @interface ControllerTest {
}
```

Then, I used only one annotation for all my `ControllerTest classes`

```
@ControllerTest
public class XXControllerTest {
}
```

After this modification the tests failed with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
```

And to make it work again it required me to add the `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` to the `Test class`

```
@ControllerTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class XXControllerTest {
}
```

My question is why my `@ControllerTest` annotation doesn't work while its contain the `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation? is there anything special about the `@RunWith` annotation? or did I miss something?

PS: I use the same approach for `Spring config classes` and they work just fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This mechanism, where you can have "meta-annotations" that are themselves annotated with other annotations, which then apply to the class on which you put your meta-annotation, is something that is specific to the Spring Framework. It is not a standard feature of Java annotations.

It doesn't work because JUnit does not understand this mechanism. The `@RunWith` annotation is a JUnit annotation. JUnit does not understand that it should look at the annotations that are on your `@ControllerTest` meta-annotation.

So, this mechanism works with annotations that are processed by Spring, but not with annotations that are processed by other tools such as JUnit.

Comment: Should it work for my case ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77229486/how-to-pass-argument-of-meta-annotation-to-inner-annotaion

Answer (score 3):

Creating [meta-annotations](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-meta-annotations) out of spring annotations  is a spring feature and `@RunWith` is a JUnit annotation.