# Can I aggregate, proxy, or imitate @SuppressWarnings in Java?

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I use Spring to build a ModelMap, which is rendered and then parsed by Mustache. For this reason, I have some classes that only exist to wrap data for Mustache's convenience.

These classes have fields and methods that are never used in the code, but are in fact used by Spring (and, in turn, Mustache). I want to explicitly state that this is intentional by annotating the class with a custom annotation `@ForMustache` that looks like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface ForMustache {
}
```

My goal is basically a fancy way of saying `@SuppressWarnings("unused") // For Mustache`.

I attempted to annotate `ForMustache` with `@SuppressWarnings("unused")`, but its effects apply inside my annotation instead of being propagated to the type annotated with `@ForMustache`.

Can I proxy or imitate `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` with another annotation?

Comment: No, these annotations are meant for the compiler and it will only apply them verbatim to the element they are on. But maybe there is a way not to trigger that warning.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345605/java-custom-annotation-aggregate-multiple-annotations) is very closely related to what you're trying to do (you're just trying to create a meta-annotation that only contains one annotation rather than multiple). This may even be a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @zapl Thanks for the hint, I'll try to investigate!

Comment: @JonK No, I don't think it is, because of the nature of SuppressWarnings. Besides, The annotations are processed by Spring, so "meta-annotations" are available to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@SuppressWarnings` annotation is meant for the compiler and other compile time tools that work directly on the source files.

It is also specified as

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface SuppressWarnings { ...
```

meaning it's not supposed to be available anymore at runtime. This means that even springs meta-annotation aware processing can't see it anymore.

Given enough time, you could build an annotation processor that, during compile-time, transforms a custom `@ForMustache` annotation into a `@SuppressWarnings` so the compiler can pick it up. In similar fashion [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) can turn

```
@Data
class Foo {
    private final String value;
}
```

into a) code that compiles and doesn't complain about no assignment to a final field and b) it wouldn't generate a warning because it generates a public getter for the field. Those can only be assumed to be used / they are usable from places outside the compiler's reach.

Besides putting `@SuppressWarnings` everywhere, your only chance is to remove the condition that causes the warning.

- Disable the check with a compiler option
- add public getters or other code so the fields are used (with lombok for example)
- hook into the compile process.

Comment: Great answer! I did consider the option of writing an annotation processor, but it seems like way too much effort for this goal. Thanks a lot for your suggestions!