# Using Swagger 2.0 reusable parameters with springfox

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0, springfox

Swagger 2.0 has support for reusable parameters, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27013123/872832).

How would i take advantage of this feature using [Springfox](https://github.com/springfox/springfox)

Is this feature supported in Springfox?

Comment: In general reusable parameters are useful when designing spec-first. Since springfox is code-first approach, that is not really a thing.

Comment: I think reusable parameters are also useful in code-first approach. If you want your API properly documented, this feature would save you many lines of repetitive @ApiParam annotations (if you have many operations with many reused parameters)

Comment: But based on your comment, i guess answer is NO, it is not supported :)

Comment: A better technique for reuse in your case since you're in the spring ecosystems is [annotation aggregation/meta annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33345605/java-custom-annotation-aggregate-multiple-annotations)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on comment from [Dilip Krishnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19219/dilip-krishnan), Springfox currently does not support this feature.

Comment: That is a 100% true statement. However I will restate the fact that with springfox, you dont need to define `ApiParam` annotations on any parameter, unless you're trying to influence default behavior. It is one of [the goals](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/current/#goals) of the project.